# "interact" doesn't work when expect script contents are piped into

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I am building a simple ssh login wrapper tool to help auto login to one of a hell of a lot of servers.
It first takes descriptions from user input and then extract the corresponding (most relevant) server IP and password stored safely somewhere, using which it creates a piece of expect script.

The expect script looks something like this:

```
    spawn ssh2 -q -t Bob@172.23.24.35
    expect {
        "assword:" {send "Bob123\r"}
    }
    interact
```

When I pipe this to expect (expect can read script from stdin) everything 
goes well until  it reaches “interact". 
Expect claims that it receives eof and 
terminates immediately. Then I store this into a file say tmp.exp the same problem 
happens when I do "expect < tmp.exp". However when I execute "expect -f tmp.exp" 
everything is OK.

I think that the reason is "interact" takes input from fd0 which is redirected to a pipe by my program (or shell). 
Does this mean that I can not use interact when I do 
something like "expect < xx.exp" ? 
Is there a way to resume fd0 to the real terminal before the "interact" command? 
I googled a lot and all I got is something like 'close_on_eof 0'. I can't find it's meaning nor how it works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just come up with a way to do that. See this example:

```
$ cat foo.exp
if {[catch {
    #  Close stdin and reopen it as /dev/tty. Then we are
    #+ connecting to a tty.
    close stdin
    open /dev/tty
} err]} {
    puts stderr $err
    exit 1
}

# Without this, inputed lines will be echo'ed twice.
set stty_init -echo
spawn bash --noprofile --norc

expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+(#|\$) }
interact

exit
$ expect < foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.2# ptree $$
705   screen -T dtterm -U
  24164 bash
    26826 expect
      26827 bash --noprofile --norc
        26830 ptree 26827
bash-4.2# exit
exit
$
```

To make it more smart we need to check if `stdin` is a tty or not at the beginning.

Comment: This indeed works! However some of the terminal properties seem to be messed up. For example when i login to another server this way and strike backspace, it prints a '^H' symbol instead of deleting the last character. And typing "exit" does not quit the session. The local file version is all OK and i guess i don't want to go further to deal with terminals.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `Tcl` or `Expect` provides a built-in way to check if a file descriptor is a tty or not. I did that this way:

```
$ cat foo.exp
if { [catch { system {[[ -t 0 ]]} } error] } {
    puts "stdin is not a tty"
} else {
    puts "stdin is a tty"
}
$ expect foo.exp
stdin is a tty
$ expect < foo.exp
stdin is not a tty
$
```